# Jaxb accepts xml with extra parameters for unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a servlet which accepts a rectangle xml and adds it to existing xml database. It works fine except it accepts such an xml with any amount of extra parameters as well:

```
<rectangle>
    <width>100</width>
    <height>100</height>
    <someparam>param</someparam>
</rectangle>
```

despite the xml being the wrong format servlet returns 200 OK and adds a new rectangle to database but only taking the width and height parameters and omitting extra ones. How can I make sure that only rectangles with two parameters: width and height are accepted?

Rectangle class:

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder = {"width", "height"})
public class Rectangle{
    private int width, height;
    
    public Rectangle(){}

    public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }    

    public int getDiagonal(){
        return (int)Math.sqrt(width * width + height * height);
    }

    public int getPerimeter(){
        return 2 * (width + height);
    }

    public int getArea(){
        return width * height;
    }

    public boolean validate(){
        return width > 0 && height > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Rectangle [" + width + ", " + height + "]";
    }
}
```

Unmarshalling code:

```
//Servlet passes request.getInputStream() as input argument
public static Rectangle streamToRectangle(InputStream input) throws UnmarshalException, JAXBException{
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Rectangle.class);

    Rectangle rectangle = (Rectangle) context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(input);

    return rectangle;
}
```